# Finding out if a std::type_info object is a subtype of another std::type_info object in C++

Tags: c++, types, rtti, subtype

I have two pointers `std::type_info t1` and `std::type_info t2`.
How can I find out if `t1` is a subtype of `t2`?
I have no other information available.

Comment: Did you try [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)? Where did the typeinfo come from?

Comment: A `type_info` only represents information about the name of types and some implementation-defined ordering information.    If two `subtype`s compare equal, they correspond to the same actual type.   However, there is no way to get information about other relationships (such as subtyping) between the actual types.

Comment: `std::type_info t1` is the type of an exception, which I intercept.

Comment: @Peter that surprises me, how does gcc or clang implement catch internally then?

Comment: If you catch an exception, then surely you have a pointer to the exception object, no?

Comment: There is no requirement that an implementation only use information in a `type_info` to implement exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

> I have two pointers `std::type_info t1` and `std::type_info t2`. How can I find out if `t1` is a subtype of `t2`? I have no other information available

The standard does not define any relationships between two instances of `std::type_info`. Unless your platform provides additional information, you cannot determine whether the type corresponding `t1` is a subtype of the type corresponding to `t2`.